# make preprocessor trace the source of a definition

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

In a large and complex pile of source (not invented here, hacked together by Elbonian code-slaves) it can be the case that several bits of code have their own local duplicate of some common header file in their path.

Due to the many layers of build and use of [guard macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html) to prevent re-definition, a value #defined in one place may therefore be remembered by the compiler and used elsewhere despite a more "local" header #defining the same thing.

**My question is**: Can I get the C preprocessor to spit out the name/path of the file where it originally "found" the definition of something?

Comment: Did you try the gcc option `-fdebug-cpp`? I've never used it, but I saw it in the gcc documentation. (You have to also specify `-E` for it to take effect.)

Comment: I hadn't found that, it looks like it might provide an (overly verbose) solution. I was more hoping for some sort of command or directive like `#pragma trace(mydefine)` (which I just made up) which would tell me, in a given source file, where `mydefine` came from.

Comment: rici seems to be on a more generic and more mature path, I recommend that one. If you want a more "direct" way, did you consider changing the definitions (those several which are suspected to be the source) with easily recognisable distinct definitions. Then either preprocess-only the using file or just compile and hope for a telling compiler error. This is more manual work but less tinkering with the tools, existing or added.