# print pre-processor macros when using ARM CROSS COMPILER and Makefile

Tags: makefile, c-preprocessor, cross-compiling

I want to print out all #define macros when compiling u-boot using ARM cross compiler.

According to [GCC dump preprocessor defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines) link I can add -dM -E flags to achieve this. However using

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- CFLAGS=-dM

does not print out any #define macros.

Is there way to achieve this and print out all #define macros to a txt file?

Comment: You forgot the `-E`. However, if you add the `-E`, you are telling gcc to perform preprocessing only, so it will perform not *compilation*, and your build will presumably fail.

Comment: Close to a duplicate. You might find the discussion interesting in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844545/evaluate-all-macros-in-a-c-header-file/42940455#42940455 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652595/make-preprocessor-trace-the-source-of-a-definition#comment73146796_40652595.

Comment: Both of them do not include an answer to my problem. I want to print out all #define macros when I run make command. How to do it?

Comment: I have the same issue. `-dM -E` seems to work with gcc don't work with the cross-compile gcc version, I'm not sure why. I've also tried passing `-dM` using `-Wp,-dM` and `-Xpreprocessor -dM` but that hasn't helped.